# Primefaces Menu bar not working in Mobile Browsers

Tags: android, jsf, primefaces, mobile-browser

Primefaces menu bar in a JSF application can not be accessed in any of the Mobile Browser in Android. Clicking the top level submenu do not bring the dropdown? How Can I change that?

Comment: You are using Primefaces Mobile, or the normal edition ?

Comment: Standard Primefaces is not designed to preserve all its properties in mobile devices. That's why PF Mobile exists, as @HatemAlimam says.

Comment: I use normal edition, not the mobile edition. Does it mean the web applications developed with normal edition is not accessible with the Mobile devices like tablets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your p:menubar tag adds the property autoDisplay="false".

Exemple:

```
<p:menubar autoDisplay="false">
```

This will make the submenu don't show up when mouse hover, just by mouse click. And at mobile this will work also.

Answer (score 0):

I used separate pages for mobile access using PrimeFaces Mobile. Then there is no need to address this issue.